# В каких случаях в профиле участника отображается текст (незарегистрированный)?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника, cookie

Раньше я думал, что это возникает кратковременно для новых участников. Но сейчас я вижу это в [профиле участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206829/abvgd) с 10 месячным стажем:

> [image: профиль]

Правда, стоит заметить, что все эти 10 месяцев он не появлялся на сайте и его даже нельзя найти поиском по нику:

> [image: поиск]

Что вообще такое "незарегистрированный участник"? Что он может, а что нет?

Comment: Неактивированный? Т. е. мыло не подтвердил.

Comment: @Other я тоже мыло не подтверждал на SO. Вообще через google захожу :)

Comment: Ну гугл - доверенная весчь, считай подтвердился.

Comment: _В каких случаях в профиле участника отображается текст (незарегистрированный)_ - когда участник **незарегистрирован**? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, tnx, KO.

Comment: @Grundy в чем заключается регистрация?

Comment: Вероятно, в наличии логина с паролем, либо другого постоянного способа входа на сайт.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>На основании [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68525/339911) [@BalusC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138231/balusc):</sub>

Незарегистрированный участник (пользователь) заходит на сайт используя только лишь сохранённый на определённом компьютере/браузере куки. В частности он не задавал пару логин/пароль на сайтах сети *Stack Exchange* и не использовал возможности какого-то провайдера *OpenID* (типа *Google*, *Facebook* и т.п.). Он не может зайти на сайт под этой же учётной записью на другом компьютере/браузере.

Есть ли какие-то дополнительные ограничения, пока не ясно. Кроме того, что участника не найти через поиск по имени.

Comment: Не понял - все мы под куками ходим, в чём особенность?

Comment: @Other уточнил ответ.

Comment: Если он не задавал логин - откуда он?

Comment: @Other речь именно о паре (логин+пароль), под логином понимается Email. В частности для публикации вопроса ["анонимно"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK8r7.png) (?) (без регистрации) надо задать имя (не логин) и Email.

Comment: Да, вспомнил. Тогда всё ясно.

Comment: Предлагаю перевести "незарегистрированный" как "анонимный".

Comment: @Other я думаю, правильнее убрать ошибочный перевод "Отправить анонимно", т.к. в оригинале это "Post as a guest". И анонимности как-то не видно, всё-таки надо указать имя и какой-то Email.

Comment: Гость - идеально.